# Questions about scala.concurrent.Blocking

Tags: scala

I believe the following to be true. Corrections and clarifications are welcome:

I/O bound tasks can tie up threads and idle them for extended periods of time. The [`global`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext$$Implicits$@global:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor) threadpool has special provision for detecting and handling specially marked code within `Future`s that block. Code contained within a `blocking {}` block within a `Future` that is backed by a `ForkJoin` threadpool will be monitored for idleness, and extra threads will be allocated as necessary. Enclosing code within `blocking {}` that is not executed by a `Future` which is backed by a suitably configured `ForkJoin` threadpool has no effect. The [`blocking`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.package@blocking[T](body:=%3ET):T) method has the following signature:

```
def blocking[T](body: &rArr; T): T
```

`blocking` invocations seem to be designed to be aware of each other and are co-operative, via one or more `BlockContext` references which are generally of no concern to the average Scala programmer.

### Questions

1. It would seem that`f0` would behave identically with `f1` and `f2` when the global `ExecutionContext` was not backing these `Future`s. Alternatively, given this code which shows `global` is in scope, `f1` and `f2` might behave differently because `f1` might spin more threads when `rpc1` and `rpc2` block since those expressions are wrapped within `blocking` expressions.

`import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
val f0 = Future {
  val w = nonBlockingComputation1()
  val x = rpc1(param1, param2, etc)  val y = nonBlockingComputation2()
  val z = rpc2(param3, param4, etc)
  doSomethingWith(w, x, y, z)
}
val f1 = Future {
  val w = nonBlockingComputation1()
  val x = <span class="yellow">blocking</span> { rpc1(param1, param2, etc) }
  val y = nonBlockingComputation2()
  val z = blocking { rpc2(param3, param4, etc) }
  doSomethingWith(w, x, y, z)
}
val f2 = Future {
  blocking {
    val w = nonBlockingComputation1()
    val x = rpc1(param1, param2, etc)
    val y = nonBlockingComputation2()
    val z = rpc2(param3, param4, etc)
    doSomethingWith(w, x, y, z)
  }
}`

2. Does Scala 2.11.4 in fact handle the execution of `f1` and `f2` differently?
3. Is this behavior expected to change in future Scala releases?
4. How can a custom `ForkJoin` threadpool, for example this one one provided by Akka's configuration, be enhanced so it also supports `blocking`?

   ```
   import scala.concurrent._
   import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

   val config = """
             |akka {
             |  my-dispatcher {
             |    type = Dispatcher
             |    executor = "fork-join-executor"
             |    fork-join-executor {
             |      parallelism-min = 2
             |      parallelism-factor = 2.0
             |      parallelism-max = 10
             |    }
             |    throughput = 100
             |  }
             |}
             |""".stripMargin

   implicit val executionContext = system.dispatchers.lookup("my-dispatcher")
   ```
5. Aleksandar Prokopec told me that the easiest way to make a custom `ExecutionContext` that responds to the `blocking` hint is to wrap `ForkJoinPool` and implement the `execute` method so that it sets your own `BlockContext` object, or that the worker threads are `BlockContext` objects. See: [github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/concurrent/BlockContext.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/concurrent/BlockContext.scala). Unfortunately that did not tell me much. Can anyone show me a concrete example?